# How to redirect input and output in Eclipse program

Tags: java

I have a program that I made in Eclipse which has a console menu (just plain text) and takes user input using Scanner. I need to make it automated so that I can run the program from command line in the following manner:java MyProgramName <  input.txt  > output.txt

I have tried placing the following in my main:

```
try {
    System.setIn(new FileInputStream("input.txt"));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    System.out.println("input.txt does not exist!");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1585)
```

Does anybody know what is wrong here?

EDIT: It might also be worthy to note that my program has 3 classes and all 3 use instances of Scanner.

Here's my semifunctional program:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

enum MONTHS
{
    January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December;
}
enum DAYS
{
    Su, Mo, Tu, We, Th, Fr, Sa;
}


public class MyCalendarTester implements java.io.Serializable {


    static MONTHS[] arrayOfMonths = MONTHS.values();
    static DAYS[] arrayOfDays = DAYS.values();
    static MyCalendar myCal = new MyCalendar();
    static Event myEvent = new Event(null, null, null);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      try {
//          System.setIn(new FileInputStream("input.txt"));
//      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
//          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//          System.out.println("input.txt does not exist!");
//          e.printStackTrace();
//      }

        Scanner in = null;
        try {
            in = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(); // capture today
        printCalendar(cal);
        menuHandler(in);

        System.out.println("\nI think we're done here!");
    }

    public static void  printCalendar(Calendar cal){

        GregorianCalendar dayCounter = new GregorianCalendar(); // capture today
        dayCounter.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

        int formatCounter = 0;

        System.out.println("    " + arrayOfMonths[cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) ] + " " + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)); //prints the month and year

        for(int i = 0; i < arrayOfDays.length; i++){
            if(i == 0){
                System.out.print(arrayOfDays[i]);
            }
            else{
                System.out.print(" " + arrayOfDays[i]);
            }
        }//print days of week

        System.out.println();
        for(int i = 0; i < arrayOfDays.length; i++){
            if(!arrayOfDays[i].equals(arrayOfDays[dayCounter.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1])){
                System.out.print("   ");
                formatCounter++;
            }
            else{
                System.out.print(" " + cal.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + " ");
                formatCounter++;
                break;
            }
        }

        for(int i = 1; i < cal.getMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); i++){
            if(formatCounter == 7){
                System.out.println();
                formatCounter = 0; //reset counter
            }
            dayCounter.roll(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, true);
            if(dayCounter.get(Calendar.DATE) == cal.get(Calendar.DATE)){
                System.out.print("[" + dayCounter.get(Calendar.DATE) + "]");
                formatCounter++;
            }
            else if(dayCounter.get(Calendar.DATE) <= 9){
                System.out.print(" " + dayCounter.get(Calendar.DATE) + " ");
                formatCounter++;
            }
            else{
                System.out.print(dayCounter.get(Calendar.DATE) + " ");
                formatCounter++;
            }


        }
    }

public static void menuHandler(Scanner in){

System.out.println("\nSelect one of the following options:");
System.out.println("[L]oad [V]iew by [C]reate [G]o to [E]vent list [D]elete [Q]uit");

        char userChoice = in.next().charAt(0);
        switch(Character.toUpperCase(userChoice)){
            case 'L':
                    MyCalendar.load();
                    menuHandler(in);
                    break;

            case 'V': 
                     myCal.viewCalendar(in);
                     menuHandler(in);
                     break;

            case 'C':
                     myEvent.createEvent(in);
                     menuHandler(in);
                     break;

            case 'G':
                    myCal.goTo(in);
                    menuHandler(in);
                    break;
            case 'E':
                    myEvent.eventList(in);
                    menuHandler(in);
                    break;

            case 'D':
                    myEvent.deleteEvent(in);
                    menuHandler(in);
                    break;

            case 'Q': MyCalendar.save();
                        break;

        }

        return;

    }




}

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.Map.Entry;


public class MyCalendar implements java.io.Serializable{

    GregorianCalendar calendar;
    private static HashMap<GregorianCalendar, Event> myCalHash;
    GregorianCalendar dayCounter = new GregorianCalendar(); // capture today
    static MONTHS[] arrayOfMonths = MONTHS.values();
    static DAYS[] arrayOfDays = DAYS.values();

    MyCalendar(){
        calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        myCalHash = new HashMap<GregorianCalendar, Event>();
    }

    public HashMap<GregorianCalendar, Event> getMyCalHash(){
        return myCalHash;
    }

    public void setMyCalHash(HashMap<GregorianCalendar, Event> myCalHash) {
        this.myCalHash = myCalHash;
    }

    public void viewCalendar(Scanner in) {

            System.out.print("[D]ay view or [M]view? ");
            char userChoice = in.next().charAt(0);
            if(Character.toUpperCase(userChoice) == 'D'){ dayView(in); }
            else if(Character.toUpperCase(userChoice) == 'M'){ monthView(in); }
            else{
                System.out.println("Invalid choice.");
            }
    }   

        public void dayView(Scanner in){
            //print day calendar
            try {
                System.setIn(new FileInputStream("input.txt"));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                System.out.println("input.txt does not exist!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            ArrayList<Event> tempArr = new ArrayList<Event>();
            System.out.println(arrayOfDays[calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1] + ", " +  arrayOfMonths[calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)] 
                    + " " + calendar.get(Calendar.DATE) + ", " + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
               for (Entry<GregorianCalendar, Event> entry : MyCalendarTester.myCal.getMyCalHash().entrySet()) {

                    if(entry.getKey().get(Calendar.MONTH) == (calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1)
                            && entry.getKey().get(Calendar.DATE) == calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)
                            && entry.getKey().get(Calendar.YEAR) == calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)){
                        tempArr.add(entry.getValue());

                    }
               }
                    if(tempArr.size() > 0){
                        Collections.sort(tempArr);
                    }
                    for(Event e: tempArr){
                        if(e.endTime != null){
                            System.out.println("    " + e.eventName + " " + e.startTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + 
                            e.startTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + " " + e.endTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) 
                            + ":" + e.endTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
                        }
                        else{
                            System.out.println(e.eventName + " " + e.startTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + 
                                    e.startTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
                        }
                    }



            System.out.print("[P]revious or [N]ext or [M]ain menu ? ");
            char userChoice = in.next().charAt(0);
            if(Character.toUpperCase(userChoice) == 'P'){
                calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
                dayView(in);
            }
            else if(Character.toUpperCase(userChoice) == 'N'){
                calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
                dayView(in);
            }
            else if(Character.toUpperCase(userChoice) == 'M'){
                return;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Invalid choice.");
                return;
            }
        }
        public void monthView(Scanner in){
            //print month calendar

            int formatCounter = 0;
            boolean eventDay = false;
            dayCounter.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

            System.out.println("    " + arrayOfMonths[calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) ] + " " + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)); //prints the month and year

            for(int i = 0; i < arrayOfDays.length; i++){
                if(i == 0){
                    System.out.print(arrayOfDays[i]);
                }
                else{
                    System.out.print(" " + arrayOfDays[i]);
                }
            }//print days of week

            System.out.println();
            for(int i = 0; i < arrayOfDays.length; i++){
                if(!arrayOfDays[i].equals(arrayOfDays[dayCounter.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1])){
                    System.out.print("   ");
                    formatCounter++;
                }
                else{
                    for (Entry<GregorianCalendar, Event> entry : MyCalendarTester.myCal.getMyCalHash().entrySet()) {
//                      System.out.println("entry.getKey().get(Calendar.MONTH) = " + (entry.getKey().get(Calendar.MONTH)) );
//                      System.out.println(" (dayCounter.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1)  = " + (dayCounter.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) );
//                      System.out.println("entry.getKey().get(Calendar.DATE) = " + entry.getKey().get(Calendar.DATE));
//                      System.out.println("(dayCounter.get(Calendar.DATE) = " + (dayCounter.get(Calendar.DATE)));
                        if(entry.getKey().get(Calendar.MONTH) == (dayCounter.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1)
                                && entry.getKey().get(Calendar.DATE) == (dayCounter.get(Calendar.DATE))
                                && entry.getKey().get(Calendar.YEAR) == dayCounter.get(Calendar.YEAR)){
                                    System.out.print("[" + calendar.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "]");
                                    formatCounter++;
                                    eventDay = true;
                                    break;
                        }
                    }
                        if(!eventDay){
                            System.out.print(" " + calendar.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + " ");
                            formatCounter++;
                            break;
                        }

                    break;
                }

            }


            for(int i = 1; i < dayCounter.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); i++){
                if(formatCounter == 7){
                    System.out.println();
                    formatCounter = 0; //reset counter
                }
                eventDay = false;
                dayCounter.roll(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, true);
                for (Entry<GregorianCalendar, Event> entry : MyCalendarTester.myCal.getMyCalHash().entrySet()) {    
                    if(entry.getKey().get(Calendar.MONTH) == (dayCounter.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1)
                            && entry.getKey().get(Calendar.DATE) == (dayCounter.get(Calendar.DATE))
                            && entry.getKey().get(Calendar.YEAR) == dayCounter.get(Calendar.YEAR)){
                            System.out.print("[" + dayCounter.get(Calendar.DATE) + "]");
                            formatCounter++;
                            eventDay = true;
                            break;

                    }
                }
                if(!eventDay){
                    if(dayCounter.get(Calendar.DATE) <= 9){
                        System.out.print(" " + dayCounter.get(Calendar.DATE) + " ");
                        formatCounter++;
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.print(dayCounter.get(Calendar.DATE) + " ");
                        formatCounter++;
                    }
                }


            }

            System.out.print("\n[P]revious or [N]ext or [M]ain menu ? ");
            char userChoice = in.next().charAt(0);
            if(Character.toUpperCase(userChoice) == 'P'){
                calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
                dayCounter.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
                monthView(in);
            }
            else if(Character.toUpperCase(userChoice) == 'N'){
                calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
                dayCounter.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
                monthView(in);
            }
            else if(Character.toUpperCase(userChoice) == 'M'){
                calendar = (GregorianCalendar) Calendar.getInstance(); //resets the calendar back to the current month
                dayCounter = (GregorianCalendar) Calendar.getInstance(); //resets the calendar back to the current month
                return;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Invalid choice.");
                return;
            }
        }

        public void goTo(Scanner in){

            System.out.print("Enter a date in MM/DD/YYYY format: ");

            String userDate = in.nextLine();
            String[] dateArr = userDate.split("/");
               dayCounter.set(GregorianCalendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(dateArr[2]));
               dayCounter.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(dateArr[0]) - 1);
               dayCounter.set(GregorianCalendar.DATE, Integer.parseInt(dateArr[1]));

             System.out.println(arrayOfDays[dayCounter.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1] + ", " +  
             arrayOfMonths[dayCounter.get(Calendar.MONTH)] + " " + dayCounter.get(Calendar.DATE) + ", " + dayCounter.get(Calendar.YEAR));

               for (Entry<GregorianCalendar, Event> entry : MyCalendarTester.myCal.getMyCalHash().entrySet()) {
                    if(entry.getKey().get(Calendar.MONTH) == Integer.parseInt(dateArr[0]) 
                            && entry.getKey().get(Calendar.DATE) == Integer.parseInt(dateArr[1]) 
                            && entry.getKey().get(Calendar.YEAR) == Integer.parseInt(dateArr[2]) ){
                        Event value = entry.getValue();

                        if(value.endTime != null){
                            System.out.println(value.eventName + " " + value.startTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + 
                                    value.startTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + " " + value.endTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) 
                                    + ":" + value.endTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
                        }else{
                            System.out.println(value.eventName + " " + value.startTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + 
                                    value.startTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

                        }

                    }
               }

        }
        public static void save(){

            SortedSet<GregorianCalendar> keys = new TreeSet<GregorianCalendar>(MyCalendarTester.myCal.getMyCalHash().keySet());
               try
                  {
                     FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("events.txt");
                     ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
                     out.writeObject(myCalHash);
                     out.close();
                     fileOut.close();
                     System.out.printf("Serialized data is saved in events.txt");
                  }catch(IOException i)
                  {
                      i.printStackTrace();
                  }
        }

        public static void load(){

              try
              {
                 FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("events.txt");
                 ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
                 myCalHash = (HashMap<GregorianCalendar, Event>) in.readObject();
                 in.close();
                 fileIn.close();
              }catch(IOException i)
              {
                 System.out.println("File not found. You must be running the program for the first time.");
                 return;
              }catch(ClassNotFoundException c)
              {
                 System.out.println("Employee class not found");
                 c.printStackTrace();
                 return;
              }

        }
}



import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.TreeSet;

import javax.xml.soap.Node;


public class Event implements Comparable, java.io.Serializable {


    String eventName;
    GregorianCalendar startTime;
    GregorianCalendar endTime;

    MyCalendarTester mCal = new MyCalendarTester();

    Event(String eventName, GregorianCalendar startTime, GregorianCalendar endTime){
        this.eventName = eventName;
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.endTime = endTime;
    } //end Event Constructor

    public GregorianCalendar getStartTime(){
        return startTime;
    }
    public void createEvent(Scanner in){

//      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the name of the event: ");
        String name = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Date of event: ");
        String dateAsString = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("dateASString = " + dateAsString);
        String startTime = null;
        String endTime = null;
        GregorianCalendar calDate = new GregorianCalendar();
        String[] dateArr = dateAsString.split("/");
           calDate.set(GregorianCalendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(dateArr[2]));
           calDate.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(dateArr[0]));
           calDate.set(GregorianCalendar.DATE, Integer.parseInt(dateArr[1]));

        System.out.print("Enter starting time and ending time(24 hour format, comma separated):");
        String times = in.nextLine();
        // checks if user entered both start and end time
        if(times.contains(",")){
            String[] time = times.split(",");
            startTime = time[0];
            endTime = time[1];

            GregorianCalendar calSTime = new GregorianCalendar();
            String[] sTime = startTime.split(":");
            calSTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(sTime[0]));
            calSTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(sTime[1]));


            GregorianCalendar calETime = new GregorianCalendar();
            String[] eTime = endTime.split(":");
            calETime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(eTime[0]));
            calETime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(eTime[1]));


            Event myEvent = new Event(name, calSTime, calETime); 


            MyCalendarTester.myCal.getMyCalHash().put(calDate,  myEvent); //adding date and event to HashMap

        }else{ //if user did not specify an event end time
            startTime = times;
            endTime = null;

            GregorianCalendar calSTime = new GregorianCalendar();
            String[] sTime = startTime.split(":");
            calSTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(sTime[0]));
            calSTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(sTime[1]));
            Event myEvent = new Event(name, calSTime, null);
            MyCalendarTester.myCal.getMyCalHash().put(calDate,  myEvent);//adding date and event to HashMap
        }




    }

    public void deleteEvent(Scanner in){


    //Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("[S]elected or [A]ll ?");
        char userChoice = in.next().charAt(0);
        if(Character.toUpperCase(userChoice) == 'S'){ 
            //delete all events on the day

            System.out.println("Enter the date: ");

            String deleteDate = in.nextLine();

                String[] parsed = deleteDate.split("/");
                System.out.println("MyCalendarTester.myCal.getMyCalHash().size() = " + MyCalendarTester.myCal.getMyCalHash().size());

                SortedSet<GregorianCalendar> keys = new TreeSet<GregorianCalendar>(MyCalendarTester.myCal.getMyCalHash().keySet());

                for (GregorianCalendar entry :  keys) {
                    GregorianCalendar copyEntry = entry;
                    if(entry.get(Calendar.MONTH) == Integer.parseInt(parsed[0]) 
                            && entry.get(Calendar.DATE) == Integer.parseInt(parsed[1]) 
                            && entry.get(Calendar.YEAR) == Integer.parseInt(parsed[2]) ){
                                MyCalendarTester.myCal.getMyCalHash().remove(copyEntry);

                    }

                }

        }
        else if(Character.toUpperCase(userChoice) == 'A'){ 
            MyCalendarTester.myCal.getMyCalHash().clear();
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Invalid choice.");
        }
    }

public void eventList(Scanner in){

        int year = -1;
        GregorianCalendar tempKey = null;
        if(MyCalendarTester.myCal.getMyCalHash().equals(null)){
            System.out.println("Your calendar is empty!");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Here are your events: ");
            SortedSet<GregorianCalendar> keys = new TreeSet<GregorianCalendar>(MyCalendarTester.myCal.getMyCalHash().keySet());

            Set<Entry<GregorianCalendar, Event>> map = (MyCalendarTester.myCal.getMyCalHash().entrySet()); 

            List<Map.Entry> list = new LinkedList<Map.Entry>(map);

//          Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<GregorianCalendar, Event>>() {
//              public int compare(Map.Entry<GregorianCalendar, Event> e1, Map.Entry<GregorianCalendar,Event> e2) {
//                  
//                  return ( e1.getValue()).compareTo(e2.getValue());
//             
//              }
//          });
//          Iterator i2 = list.iterator();
//          while (i2.hasNext()) {
//              System.out.print(i2.next() + " , ");
//          }
//          
            for(GregorianCalendar key : keys){
                Event value = MyCalendarTester.myCal.getMyCalHash().get(key);
                tempKey = key;
                if(value.endTime != null){
                    if(key.get(Calendar.YEAR) == year){

                        System.out.println(MyCalendarTester.arrayOfDays[key.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1] + ", " + MyCalendarTester.arrayOfMonths[key.get(Calendar.MONTH) - 1] + " "
                                + key.get(Calendar.DATE) + " " + value.startTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + value.startTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + " - " + value.endTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) 
                                + ":" + value.endTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + " " + value.eventName);

                    }else{
                        System.out.println(key.get(Calendar.YEAR));
                        System.out.println(MyCalendarTester.arrayOfDays[key.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1] + ", " + MyCalendarTester.arrayOfMonths[key.get(Calendar.MONTH) - 1] + " "
                                + key.get(Calendar.DATE) + " " + value.startTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + value.startTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + " - " + value.endTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) 
                                + ":" + value.endTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + " " + value.eventName );
                        year = key.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                    }

                }else{
                    if(key.get(Calendar.YEAR) == year){
                        System.out.println(MyCalendarTester.arrayOfDays[key.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1] + ", " + MyCalendarTester.arrayOfMonths[key.get(Calendar.MONTH) - 1] + " "
                                + key.get(Calendar.DATE) + " " + value.startTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + value.startTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + " " + value.eventName);

                    }else{
                        System.out.println(key.get(Calendar.YEAR));
                        System.out.println(MyCalendarTester.arrayOfDays[key.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1] + ", " + MyCalendarTester.arrayOfMonths[key.get(Calendar.MONTH) - 1] + " "
                                + key.get(Calendar.DATE) + " " + value.startTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + value.startTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE)  + " " + value.eventName);
                        System.out.println();
                        year = key.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                    }
                }

            }

        }

    }
@Override
    public int compareTo(Object e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(((Event) e).mCal.myCal.getMyCalHash().get(Calendar.MONTH) == (this.mCal.myCal.getMyCalHash().get(Calendar.MONTH))
            && ((Event) e).mCal.myCal.getMyCalHash().get(Calendar.DATE) == (this.mCal.myCal.getMyCalHash().get(Calendar.DATE))
            && ((Event) e).mCal.myCal.getMyCalHash().get(Calendar.YEAR) == (this.mCal.myCal.getMyCalHash().get(Calendar.YEAR))){

       int hour = ((Event) e).getStartTime().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
       int minute = ((Event) e).getStartTime().get(Calendar.MINUTE);
       int anotherHour = this.startTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
       int anotherMinute = this.startTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

       if(anotherHour - hour == 0 ){
           return anotherMinute - minute;
       }else{
           return anotherHour - hour;
       }
    }

    return 0;

    }
}



//  
//static <GregorianCalendar,Event extends Comparable<? super Event>> 
//List<Entry<GregorianCalendar, Event>> entriesSortedByValues(Map<GregorianCalendar,Event> map) {
//
//List<Entry<GregorianCalendar,Event>> sortedEntries = new ArrayList<Entry<GregorianCalendar,Event>>(map.entrySet());
//
//Collections.sort(sortedEntries, 
//new Comparator<Entry<GregorianCalendar,Event>>() {
//    @Override
//    public int compare(Entry<GregorianCalendar,Event> e1, Entry<GregorianCalendar,Event> e2) {
//        return e2.getValue().compareTo(e1.getValue());
//    }
//}
//);
//
//return sortedEntries;
//}
//
//}
```

Comment: though if i had to guess, i'd say your simply reading lines without  checking availability

Comment: @Paul My entire program? That might be a bit overkill. It's 3 classes. Or are there specific part I should post?

Comment: the specific parts should do

Comment: Sorry, I just posted all of it. Problem is, I'm using Scanner all throughout my program.

Comment: Where in the code is the exception exactly thrown?

Comment: createEvent right here: String[] dateArr = dateAsString.split("/"); It's not reading the input file right. It starts from the very beginning of it again in the method.

Comment: that's strange, i've looked over the code and simply can't find any mistakes. Either your file is corrupted, or your scanner is buggy.

Comment: It's an extremely basic text file with 1 string per line. I can open it with notepad. How can a Scanner be buggy? Anything I can try to fix it?

Comment: nope, you could debug in the scanner, but apart from that nothing comes to my mind. i'll look over this tomorrow, time to go to sleep.

Comment: well, i've absolutely no idea what could possibly be wrong

Comment: only thing that come to my mind: you could send me the input.txt and i debug the whole thing

Comment: @Paul Scanner is just stupid. When I added in.nextLine() after the name scan, it stopped immediately moving on the the next scan and worked. I'm using bufferedReader next time. But thank you for your offer to help!

Answer (score 0):

continue to use Scanner but use this constructor

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
```

Comment: Will Scanner know where it left off in the file? I'm using one single file to run the whole program, but I'm instantiating multiple Scanners.

Comment: No, avoid having multiple Scanners, just create one and pass it to each class.

Comment: I did that, but now it's complaining about ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException after reading the 3rd line in the file. Yet the input is no different than what I would manually type in. Any ideas what could be the case?

Comment: Ok, one sec, I'll post the mess that I have. Upon further inspection, it seems like it starts reading from the beginning of the file instead of the next line.